# Check of checkmate in chess

Tags: algorithm, chess

I am using [this](http://amitcodes.com/2014/02/04/object-oriented-design-for-chess-game/) object oriented design of chess. I have implemented generating of valid moves for all pieces. Now I am trying implement check of checkmate.

I tried to make a method, which if player have moves, which cancel the checkmate. But the program end with StackOverflowError.

I delete the method. But the pseudoalgorithm of the method was something like that

```
boolean isGameOver(arg){
    if(playerIsInCheck){
        if(!hasValidMoves){
            print("checkmate");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!hasValidMoves){
            print("stalemate");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to check if the move cancel the checkmate. Can anyone advise me? I do not need all the code written in any programming language. Pseudoalgorithm will be sufficient.

Comment: Its hard to see what is going wrong here without seeing some code. One thing I would do is invert the if statements here, `if(hasValidMoves) return false;` then decide on which type of game ending situation has occurred after that.

Comment: The algorithm looks correct to me.  I would suspect it is the implementation of the hasValidMoves; be careful not to call isGameOver in the hasValidMoves; you cannot have circular definitions.

Comment: If a function recursively calls it self too many times, it can cause stack over flow errors.

Comment: @MarcJohnston the hasValidMoves was condition if number of valid moves of all pieces is greater than zero

Comment: Yes, but how do you determine the validity of the move? Do you execute the move on the board, subsequently  calling `isGameOver` ? If you do, voilà, you have infinite recursion.

Comment: @vincentleest the method didn't call recursively it self. It used return of other methods.

Comment: @collapsar I have method when I copy the 2D array of pieces to temporary array and I make the move and check if the king is in check with method isInCheck

Comment: You need to provide more concrete code. Stack overflow errors are typical indicators of a runaway recursion, and the recursive dependency may be far from obvious ( c_0 calls c_1 calls ... calls c_n calls c_0 ).

Comment: @collapsar I will try write the code again and when I get again the StackOverflowError I will paste it here. Have a nice day.

Comment: As an aside, if you copy the whole board for testing the consequences of a single move, your code risks being horribly inefficient. As a second aside, does your code recognize draw by repetition? (this requires maintaining the history of board states that occurred during the game, either explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: Basically, if you want to write a chess engine properly, you will need to do A* search with cycle checking...

Comment: So I wrote it again. I tried to write the methods little different, but still it throw StackOverflowError

Comment: @Alda It's hopeless to ask here if you don't have the code. You'll need to debug it yourself to a specific part of the code. It's part of the learning exercise. In any case, nobody will do it in your way. It's not what the traditional approach.

Comment: A possible way to check for things like interposition or capture of checking piece would be to generate all the possible moves for all pieces in the position, and then from each of those positions evaluate whether the checkmated side really is in checkmate. If all the second-level positions still have check, it is checkmate.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for checking for checkmate is as follows:

```
public boolean checkmated(Player player) {
  if (!player.getKing().inCheck() || player.isStalemated()) {
      return false; //not checkmate if we are not 
                    //in check at all or we are stalemated.
  }

  //therefore if we get here on out, we are currently in check...

  Pieces myPieces = player.getPieces();

  for (Piece each : myPieces) {

      each.doMove(); //modify the state of the board

      if (!player.getKing().inCheck()) { //now we can check the modified board
          each.undoMove(); //undo, we dont want to change the board
          return false;
          //not checkmate, we can make a move, 
          //that results in our escape from checkmate.
      }

      each.undoMove();

  }
  return true; 
  //all pieces have been examined and none can make a move and we have       
  //confimred earlier that we have been previously checked by the opponent
  //and that we are not in stalemate.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why you are getting a stack overflow without seeing your method definitions, but I can explain how you check for mate-cancelling moves ( no pseudocode, sorry).

Basically, you generate a List of all possible Moves (Pseudolegals) and you let your programm try each of them. If the players king is no longer hittable in the resulting position (in your case you use the IsInCheck method), the current move is cancelling the mate.

If you do need the pseudocode, write a comment and I'll see what I can do.